# LazyVGrid child views don't update bindings unless they're part of the first rendered group

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

My app uses a LazyVGrid to display a collection of child views and I'm using a `$selection` bound to the child views to ensure that only one child view is selected at once. This "selection" just displays an overlay on the child view with buttons (so when a child view is selected, an overlay shows up, and if user selects a second child view, the overlay disappears from first child view and appears on second child view).

I simplified the problem down to the example shown below, where the `$selection` merely changes the text to red and ensures only one child view has red text at a time. This code is based on the default Xcode project.

## Problem

The child view bindings only get updated if they're part of the first 8 child views, the first 8 that are rendered. Scrolling to further child views and selecting them causes the `$selection` variable to update properly in the main view, but only the first 8 child views register this change.

## Video of Problem

https://youtube.com/shorts/7zBjwZwPkYA

This video shows that long pressing on the child views only works for the first 8. If you long press on view 12, for example, child views 1-8 register the changed `$selection` but no others do.

## Code

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.index, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default)
    private var items: FetchedResults<Item>
    
    @State var selection: UUID?
    @State var index: Int16 = 1

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                LazyVGrid(columns: [(GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 160)))], content: {
                    ForEach(items) { item in
                        
                        ItemView(selection: $selection, item: item)
                            .aspectRatio(1.0, contentMode: .fill)
                            .padding(20)
                            

                    }
                    .onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
                })
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    EditButton()
                }
                ToolbarItem {
                    Button(action: addItem) {
                        Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
                    }
                }
            }
            Text("Select an item")
        }
    }

    private func addItem() {
        withAnimation {
            let newItem = Item(context: viewContext)
            newItem.index = index
            index += 1
            newItem.id = UUID()

            do {
                try viewContext.save()
            } catch {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                let nsError = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }

    private func deleteItems(offsets: IndexSet) {
        withAnimation {
            offsets.map { items[$0] }.forEach(viewContext.delete)

            do {
                try viewContext.save()
            } catch {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                let nsError = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
}


struct ItemView: View {
    
    @Binding var selection: UUID?
    @ObservedObject var item: Item
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                if selection == item.id {
                    Text(String(item.index))
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .foregroundColor(.red)
                } else {
                    Text(String(item.index))
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                }
                Spacer()
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .background(Color.secondary)
        .onLongPressGesture {
            if selection == item.id {
                selection = nil
            } else {
                selection = item.id
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: selection, perform: { _ in
            print("Child view \(String(item.index)) says selection changed")
        })

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for providing code, but it would be good if your example could show what is happening without relying on CoreData. You could simplify by just using an array of `Item` structs

Comment: Hello, same issue for me, here is a sample code : https://gist.github.com/floriangbh/494bd91d860b1f9147c875bd8fcd531b

Did you manage to a solution Christian ?

Comment: I did not. I found a workaround specific to my case where I removed the selection binding from the child view and moved it up the view hierarchy. So It didn't solve the problem, merely got rid of the problem.

Shame, seems like a clear cut bug Apple could fix.